# Package "preview" + parskip?

Tags: parskip, preview

Using the "preview"-package, I want to put several paragraphs into one preview-environment. This works; however, any parskip-setting seems to be ignored.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\setlength\parskip{10pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

In the result, there is no parskip between the two paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this but I don't know the consequences ;-)

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\setlength\parskip{10pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\makeatletter
\long\def\pr@startbox#1#2{%
  \ifpr@outer
    \toks@{#2}%
    \edef\pr@cleanup{\the\toks@}%
    \setbox\pr@box\vbox\bgroup
    \break
%    \pr@outerfalse\@arrayparboxrestore
    \let\insert\pr@insert
    \let\mark\pr@mark
    \let\marks\pr@marks
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \pr@ship@start
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
     \expandafter \@gobble
  \fi{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{preview}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works! It also seems to work to only comment out the \@arrayparboxrestore. However, as I don't know much about macro programming (this seems to be quite sophisticated to me), I have no idea what this solution does or whether it might have any side effects. I will try to see what happens with more complicated examples...

Answer (score 0):

use an own `\Par`

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\Par{\endgraf\vspace{10pt}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\blindtext\Par

\blindtext
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the part I want to preview comes from an external source, so I do not have the possibility to insert macros in between the text.

Thanks for your help, though!